Secure Store Service Application endpoint with fully qualified domain name
The IIS site 'SharePoint Web Services' hosts the service application endpoints.
I am currently facing a certificates issue with the Secure Store.
In the SharePoint trace log below, it shows that connections are established with the server name only and not with a fully qualified domain name like for example servername.company.net.
WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'https://servername:32844/1f83cd6613794b84b84c588543c1de48/SecureStoreService.svc/https' 
The Secure Store Service application Secure Store Service Application Proxy is not accessible. The full exception text is: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'servername:32844'.

I could resolve the issue by issuing and applying a new domain certificate. However, my company has standardized on public certificates everywhere for automation reasons. The current certificate includes all applicable DNS names except for the raw servername.
My question now is - can a SharePoint Service Application be reconfigured with a new Uri endpoint using the fully qualified domain name? I have been looking into this with PowerShell with Get-SPServiceApplication and Set-SPServiceApplication. But so far without luck.
